# Transpose one line/lines from column to row using shell

Tags: shell, unix

I want convert a column of data in a `txt` file to a row of a `csv` file using unix commands.

example:

```
ApplChk1,
ApplChk2,
v_baseLoanAmountTI,
v_plannedClosingDateField,
downPaymentTI,
```

this is a column which  present in a txt file

I want output as follows in a csv file

```
ApplChk1,ApplChk2,v_baseLoanAmountTI,v_plannedClosingDateField,downPaymentTI,
```

Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If that's a single column, which you want to convert to row, then there are many possibilities:

```
tr -d '\n' < filename ; echo # option 1 OR
xargs echo -n < filename ; echo # option 2 (This option however, will shrink spaces & eat  quotes) OR
while read x; do echo -n "$x" ; done < filename; echo # option 3
```

Please let us know, how the input would look like, for multi-line case.

Comment: How is it not working? What output do you get instead of the expected output?

Comment: I got an error like -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'

Comment: What is your bash version? This is one of the standard syntaxes for `while loop`.

Comment: This is a [UUOC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html). Use `tr -d '\n' < filename` instead.

Comment: Neither of the 3 options worked? what is the output of `bash --version`?

Comment: bash version is version 3.00.15(1)

Comment: Your first option makes this problem trivial and should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A funny *pure* bash solution (bash ≥ 4.1):

```
mapfile -t < file.txt; printf '%s' "${MAPFILE[@]}" $'\n'
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `< file.txt` ; do echo -n $i; done; echo ""
```

gives the output

```
ApplChk1,ApplChk2,v_baseLoanAmountTI,v_plannedClosingDateField,downPaymentTI,
```

To send output to a file:

```
{ for i in `< file.txt` ; do echo -n $i ; done; echo; } > out.csv
```

When I run it, this is what happens:

```
[jenny@jennys:tmp]$ more file.txt 
ApplChk1,
ApplChk2,
v_baseLoanAmountTI,
v_plannedClosingDateField,
downPaymentTI,
[jenny@jenny:tmp]$ { for i in `< file.txt` ; do echo -n $i ; done; echo; } > out.csv
[jenny@jenny:tmp]$ more out.csv 
ApplChk1,ApplChk2,v_baseLoanAmountTI,v_plannedClosingDateField,downPaymentTI,
```

Comment: how to send the output to a csv file for the command that you used

Comment: it is not working the code is giving same output as the text present in txt file

Comment: Just to be certain here - you're looking at output in the file out.csv, not in the file file.txt, right? (And thanks, Anishsane, for the edit!)

Comment: yes i am looking at the out.csv you want me see output in file.txt

Comment: i want output in CSV file with a single row

Comment: When I run the command as written, the output goes to the file out.csv which contains one single row - just as you specified. I don't know how it can be different for you.

Comment: which command you ran either first one or second one. Can you please let me know the complete command

Comment: The second command is the one that writes output in a single row to out.csv - as I said, it works for me, and apparently for anishsane too.

Comment: ok can you please let me know the complete command to execute

Comment: The complete command is exactly as written in the last line of the answer. I do not know how to put it any clearer than that.

Comment: Hi Jenny the last line of the answer is giving same as txt file. I need all the data should be in single line

Comment: That is what the answer does. I've explained it further. If you do exactly what it says, and still get a different results, I have no idea how that can be happening.

Comment: Hi Jenny it is working fine but if i open the csv file in windows environment using Microsoft office it is displaying the data in a single column

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pe 's/\n//g' your_file
```

the above will output to stdout.
if you want to do it in place:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\n//g' your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Linux command [**sed**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) to replace line `\n` breaks by commas `,` or space   :

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g' test.txt > test.csv
```

You could also add the `-i` option if you want to change file in-place :

```
sed -i -z 's/\n/,/g' test.txt
```